# Is there a way to show second country at top of list of countries (after the default country) in CiviEvent?

Tags: civievent

I have United States set as the default country for the country field for CiviEvent registrations.

Is there a way to show Canada first on the list of the rest of the countries?

We have the most people registering for events from United States, but a fair number of people from Canada as well.  At least one person told me it is doable but didn't have any pointers to where to make the changes.

The site uses WordPress, and CiviCRM 4.6 but hopefully within a month or so up to the latest version (waiting for OK to proceed).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have participants from anywhere other than US/Canada? If it's just US/Canada you can restrict the country list to just those two (or some handful) under Admin - Localization - Languages, near the bottom of the page.

If you really do want all 200+ countries in the list, you can do a hack like this if you have access to mysql:

`update civicrm_country set name=' Canada' where name='Canada';`

(note the blank space in front - this will make it float to the top)

This might get overwritten on a future upgrade if Canada changes its name, but that seems unlikely. Still, this isn't a recommended hack, just if you're desperate.